# Trigger VBA script when any 1 cell selected containing a defined string

Tags: excel, vba

The code below worked fine so long as the "MainSubroutine" only needed to be triggered when cell G14 was clicked on, but now I need to widen the trigger event to whenever any target cell on the sheet is clicked on and it has the specific string, "Click to Learn More".

So how do I write that? I tried altering line 2 to "If Selection.Count = 1 AND selection.value = "Click to Learn More" Then..." but obviously that didn't work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G14")) Is Nothing Then
            Call MainSubroutine
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This didn't work either:

If Selection.Count = 1 Then
If Target.Value = "Click to Learn More:" Then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it? If it can contain the string use Instr or similar.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If target.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.value="Click to learn more" Then
            Call MainSubroutine
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked fine once I made the text exactly match the cell value, including upper and lower case.  Thank you!  Resolved!

Comment: Perhaps you'd be so kind as to accept the answer? To ignore case you can use `If lcase(Target.value)="click to learn more" Then`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I hadn't known how to accept an answer.